Girl gets trapped in an alternate reality while trying to avoid her sick mother
Does anyone know a movie where a girl gets trapped in an alternate reality while trying to avoid her sick mother? In the alternate reality she makes friends with a juggler (who becomes her boyfriend) and is hunted by the evil woman who is trying to control her and become her new mother. 
Also while she is in the alternate reality another girl takes her place in the 'real world'... and there are robots and other weird things in the alternate reality.

Sounds like MirrorMask from 2005:

Helena, a 15-year-old girl in a family of circus entertainers, often wishes she could run off and join real life. After a fight with her parents about her future plans, her mother falls quite ill and Helena is convinced that it is all her fault. On the eve of her mother's major surgery, she dreams that she is in a strange world with two opposing queens, bizarre creatures, and masked inhabitants. All is not well in this new world - the white queen has fallen ill and can only be restored by the MirrorMask, and it's up to Helena to find it.

Helena befriends a juggler called Valentine in that alternate reality, and discovers that a doppelganger has replaced her in her real life. Here's the trailer:



